# Laravel 5: add custom library in sub folder of "Libraries" folder

Tags: php, laravel-5, libraries

I need to add a custom library to Laravel 5, but I want to add in a sub folder of a "Libraries" folder.
I mean, I have "Libraries" folder inside "app" folder, and I would like to add another folder inside "Libraries" folder and put a class inside it.

What I've done is:

- Created "Libraries" folder inside "app" folder;
- Created "FusionChartsWrapper" folder inside "Libraries" folder;
- Created "FusionCharts.php" file inside "FusionChartsWrapper" folder.

The FusionCharts class has the correct namespace:

```
namespace App\Libraries\FusionChartsWrapper;
```

but I can not use it, cause I get this Laravel error:

```
Class 'App\Libraries\FusionChartsWrapper\FusionCharts' not found
```

If I move the class inside the "Libraries" folder, it works.
Any idea?

Comment: Did you try to run composer dump-autoload?

Comment: yes, it did not work.

Comment: Double check that name of the class in the FusionCharts.php file and the use statement. ^^

Comment: Did it without success. Indeed if I move the class inside "Libraries" folder it works.

Comment: if it works in the wrong directory then something is definitely wrong with either the class name or the namespace. You can double check the autoload files in `vendor/composer/`, but with psr-4 it should find the class in the correct location.

Comment: I checked many times the names, I read the problem probably is there, but I was not able to get the error

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to add the whole folder to autoload in composer.json file

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories",
        "app/Libraries" // =>folder you want to add
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
},
```

then run `composer dump-autoload`

Now every files in the Libraries folder can be access every where
and no need to use

`namespace App\Libraries\FusionChartsWrapper;`

just add \ before function you want to use directly